# Looking for a generic script (to use in Google Apps Script) to export a Notion database to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, notion-api

I'm looking to export a couple of database from Notion to a master Google Sheet.
The most simple way for me would be to use Apps Script as it has an integrated system of trigger to refresh the script automatically (hence the database export).

I've heard of Bardeen or Notion2Sheet that can do this. But since those software/adds-on have access to a lot of data, I would prefer creating my own script for security reasons.

I found this [article](https://max-brawer.medium.com/update-notion-databases-from-a-google-sheet-with-apps-script-c9a95df74c97) that does the other way around (Google Sheet -> Notion). Unfortunately, my programming abilities are not good enough to adapt this script to my particular use-case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm worried that I might not be able to understand your question because of my poor English skill. I think that in your situation, using Notion API is the best way as shown in your tag. But, in this case, you are required to have your access token. Have you already had the token for using the API? And also, from your question, I cannot understand the method of the Notion API you want to use. And also, I cannot know your sample input and output values. From this situation, I would like to recommend adding more information for helping users correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your answer. I'm actually a beginner programmer, that's why my request might be a little bit confusing. My purpose is to move data from a notion table to a google sheet. Is there any generic script that would transfer data from notion to google sheet? So the only thing I would have to do is replacing the dummy API key with mine and the dummy name of the notion page with mine. I hope it makes sense

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.